# BigQuery - How to remove rows after the last action in a session

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, window-functions

I have a table looks like the following:

| Session ID | Action | Position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| session_1 | 1 | 0 |
| session_1 | 0 | 1 |
| session_1 | 1 | 2 |
| session_1 | 0 | 3 |
| session_2 | 0 | 0 |
| session_2 | 1 | 1 |
| session_2 | 0 | 2 |
| session_2 | 0 | 3 |

I would like to remove rows after the last action.

The expected results should be:

| Session ID | Action | Position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| session_1 | 1 | 0 |
| session_1 | 0 | 1 |
| session_1 | 1 | 2 |
| session_2 | 0 | 0 |
| session_2 | 1 | 1 |

Answer (score 1):

One method is using a CTE to get your max(position) where action is 1 for each session id. Then join to it and return where position is less than or equal to max from the cte.

```
with cte as (
 select session_id, max(position) as max_pos
 from table1
 where action = 1
 group by session_id
 )
select t.*
from table1 t
join cte c 
  on t.session_id = c.session_id
where t.position <= c.max_pos
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
select *
from your_table
qualify Position <= max(if(Action = 1, Position, -1)) over sessions
window sessions as (partition by Session_ID)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]